Регулярные выражения с десятичной частью
Мне нужна замена таких строк с помощью регулярных выражений:
"SHS 80x3.5 | GOST 8639-82 | --"  ->  "PK80X3.5_32931_2015"
Пользуюсь таким выражением:
SHS (\d*.?\d*)x(\d*.?\d*).*$  ->  PK$1X$2_32931_2015
Но проблема в том, что если исходная строка такая: "SHS 80x3 | GOST 8639-82 | --"
То выдает следующее: "PK80X3_32931_2015"
А мне нужно, чтобы десятичный знак (после точки) обязательно был, то есть:
"SHS 80x3 | GOST 8639-82 | --"  ->  "PK80X3.0_32931_2015"
"SHS 80x3.5 | GOST 8639-82 | --"  ->  "PK80X3.5_32931_2015"
Как мне это реализовать в регулярных выражениях?
Использую регулярные выражения Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference

. - спецсимвол в регулярном выражении, который обозначает любой символ. Если вам нужна именно точка, пишите \..

@Stanislav используй вот этот сайт, там можно протестировать регулярки и вообще потренироваться их писать. А так же нужно писать на каком языке ты это реализуешь.

Если я просто добавлю .0 то для случая "SHS 80x3.5 | GOST 8639-82 | --" получится "PK80X3.5.0_32931_2015"
